# C++ Keep objects of class in array

Tags: c++, objective-c++

I'm making TD game and i wonder is there any way to keep array objects from different class. Something like code below

```
class A(base class){
  int x,y;
}
class B:A{
}
class C:A{
}

main(){
A a;
B b;
C c;
array[3];
array[0] = B b[12];
array[1] = C c[12];
foo(array[1]);
}
```

What i want achieve is get object(mobs on my map) to function without making in function a lot of 'ifs'.I just trying to avoid code like this below .

```
if(All from B is dead)
 foo(C c[all elements])
else if(All from C is dead)
 foo(D d[all elements]);
etc.
```

and do something like first code.

Thx in Advice.

Edzio

Comment: Looks like you want to make use of polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

You can approximate a polymorphic collection using `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>` or .  `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>>`.

Note that copy semantics of the vector are not good, but you might not do copy on that level at all. If that is needed, the easy way out is to create your own smart pointer and use that as above.

The heavier way is to write a real, first-class polymorphic container.

Comment: I have one solution but i'm not sure is it good enough. Just object from classes in other class - http://pastebin.com/EDuu4yQC

What do you think about it? Can be for first objective game, or better do 'hard way' from begin?

Comment: Code Review SE might be a better place to ask that

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the variety of STL containers that support polymorphism, and pick whichever suits your needs. In this case, as stated by @Balog Pal, an std::vector might be the best choice.

Here is some quality information with regards to your C++ STL container options:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/

Comment: if he can use `std::vector` then he can also use an array